# Local part cannot be “null” when creating a QName

Tags: java, apache, xsd, qnames

I use [Apache XmlSchema 2.2.1](http://ws.apache.org/xmlschema/) to parse XSD schema. I has the following schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/aigu"
       xmlns="http://www.example.com/aigu"
       xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jxb:version="2.0">
    <xs:attribute name="label" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="object">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute ref="label" form="unqualified"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The following code produces exception

```
import org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Aigu {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String schema = "HERE_IS_CONTENT_OF_SCHEMA";
        XmlSchemaCollection collection = new XmlSchemaCollection();
        collection.read(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(schema.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: local part cannot be "null" when creating a QName
    at javax.xml.namespace.QName.<init>(QName.java:244)
    at javax.xml.namespace.QName.<init>(QName.java:188)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.utils.XmlSchemaNamedWithFormImpl.setName(XmlSchemaNamedWithFormImpl.java:117)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.utils.XmlSchemaNamedWithFormImpl.setForm(XmlSchemaNamedWithFormImpl.java:105)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaAttribute.setForm(XmlSchemaAttribute.java:170)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleAttribute(SchemaBuilder.java:959)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleAttribute(SchemaBuilder.java:923)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleComplexType(SchemaBuilder.java:307)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleElement(SchemaBuilder.java:420)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleSchemaElementChild(SchemaBuilder.java:1512)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleXmlSchemaElement(SchemaBuilder.java:659)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.build(SchemaBuilder.java:157)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(XmlSchemaCollection.java:508)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(XmlSchemaCollection.java:717)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(XmlSchemaCollection.java:565)
    at com.netcracker.mediation.transition.model.xmltojava.Aigu.main(Aigu.java:23)
```

Is it a bug in Apache code or my schema is invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute `form` cannot be used in an attribute use that has a `ref` (as constrained in point 3.2 in [this paragraph of the XML Schema specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#d0e2403)).

Also, since the target of the reference is a top-level attribute declaration in a schema with a target namespace, its `form`, if it were allowed to put it explicitly, would have to be `qualified`.

It may explain the error, as the trace seems to indicate that it happens there.

This would be the corrected schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/aigu"
    xmlns="http://www.example.com/aigu"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jxb:version="2.0">
    <xs:attribute name="label" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="object">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute ref="label"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```